# Integrating Angular2 client with .NET C# server code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

A project I have taken over at work has has server code in c# and client code in Angular2 in the same project. After building the project in Visual Studio 2017 and running locally using IISExpress, changes to the Angular portion do not automatically compile like they do when using ng serve in vs code. So now if I make a change to an html file for example in the Angular portion I have to stop the project in visual studio and rerun it in order to see the changes. There's gotta be a better way to do this. Could anyone offer advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to rerun it.

But here is a start up project working with C#

https://github.com/asadsahi/AspNetCoreSpa

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.